# Get max values and indices of a high dimensional tensor

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a high dimensional tensor `a` with shape (..., H,W), i.e. the last two dims are height and width of a kernel:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

original=np.array([[[7,9,19,18],[10,11,20,16]],[[24,5,18,11],[6,10,45,12]]],dtype=np.float64)
a=as_strided(original, shape=(2,1,2,2,2),strides=(64,32*2,8*2,32,8),writeable=True)
>>> print(a)
[[[[[ 7.  9.]
    [10. 11.]]

   [[19. 18.]
    [20. 16.]]]]



 [[[[24.  5.]
    [ 6. 10.]]

   [[18. 11.]
    [45. 12.]]]]]
```

Note that `a` is Not contiguous, it's a view of `original`. I'd like to:

1. find the indices of the max values in each 2x2 kernel,
2. then obtain those max values by indexing,
3. finally change those max with, say, 1000

**requirements**
The requirement is that, **no for loops**, **use least amount of `max` or `argmax`**, and the change in values should also be reflected in the `original` tensor, i.e. **the corresponding values in `original` should also be changed to 1000.**

**What I've tried**
(with the help I got from my previous questions) I've tried flatten the last two dims, then use a single `argmax` to obtain max indices:

```
flatten=a.reshape(2,1,2,2*2)
multi_inds=flatten.argmax(-1)
i,j,k=np.indices(flatten.shape[:-1])
flatten[i, j, k,multi_inds]=1000
```

However, since `a` is not contiguous, `flatten` no longer shares the same data with `a` due to `reshape`, so max values in `a` or `original` is not changed, you can verified by using `np.info`. `a` and `original` have same data pointer, but not `flatten`:

```
>>> print(np.info(original))
...
contiguous:  True
data pointer: 0x559d75071230

>>> print(np.info(a))
...
contiguous:  False
data pointer: 0x559d75071230

>>> print(np.info(flatten))
...
contiguous:  True
data pointer: 0x559d75280900
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

original=np.array([[[7,9,19,18],[10,11,20,16]],[[24,5,18,11],[6,10,45,12]]],dtype=np.float64)
a=as_strided(original, shape=(2,1,2,2,2),strides=(64,32*2,8*2,32,8),writeable=True)

flatten=a.reshape(2,1,2,2*2)
multi_inds=flatten.argmax(-1)
i,j,k=np.indices(flatten.shape[:-1])
flatten[i, j, k,multi_inds]=1000

a=as_strided(flatten, shape=(2,1,2,2,2),strides=(64,32*2,8*2,32,8),writeable=True)
print(a)
```

applying the `strided` transformation once more to flatten and re assigning it back to a seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need values in `original` to change **the corresponding values in original should also be changed to 1000**